# How To Loop Rows (other than current row) in Subgrid using JS in Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am able to read a Subgrid cell value triggered by OnChange using **web resource**.

Following which, I would need to loop through the remaining rows (except current row) in the subgrid and read each cell value for each row.

May I know how can it be done?

---

Current code snippet:

```
function SetNA(context) {

    debugger;

    //id of the subgrid
    var id = formContext.data.entity.getId();

    // get the attribute which fired the onchange.
    var changedFirstNameAttr = context.getEventSource();

    // get the container for the attribute.
    var attrParent = changedFirstNameAttr.getParent();

    // var FirstName Field Attribute
    var changedFirstNameField = attrParent.attributes.get("firstName");

    // get the value of the changed first name value
    var changedFirstNameValue = changedFirstNameAttr.getValue();

    alert(changedFirstNameValue);

    if (changedFirstNameValue != null)
    {
        //loop through other rows in the subgrid, and read each cell value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [getRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/grids/grid/getrows) method to pull and iterate through all the editable grid rows and achieve what you want.

```
var gridRows = gridContext.getGrid().getRows();

//loop through each row to get values of each column
gridRows.forEach(function (row, i) {
    var gridColumns = row.getData().getEntity().getAttributes();
    //loop through each column in row
    gridColumns.forEach(function (column, j) {
        var atrName = column.getName();
        var atrValue = column.getValue();
        });
    });
```

[Read more](https://mahadeomatre.blogspot.com/2016/10/sub-grid-client-side-script-methods.html)

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer is correct but you can't await in a forEach. If you need to await an Xrm operation on each record, a standard for loop with a getByIndex works.

```
let rows = selectedControl.getGrid().getSelectedRows()
for (let indx = 0;indx < rows.getLength(); indx++) {
    let update = {new_fieldname:"new value"}
    let proof = rows.getByIndex(indx)
    await Xrm.WebApi.updateRecord("new_tablename", proof.data.entity.getId(), update)
            .then(res => {console.log(res);})
}
```